# Powershell clc command won't work, returns "access denied"

Tags: command-line, powershell

I'm trying to use the CLC command on a particular folder within steam, specifically the Team Fortress 2 app folder in user data so that I can start fresh with my configs/settings. Apparently running the clc command on the folder "remote" within will clear your steam cloud synchronization data. When I run as administrator and try the CLC command on the folder, I get an access denied message and I have no idea why, not very competent with powershell.

[image: [Screenshot of the problem.]]

Answer (score 0):

Be very careful using `Clear-Conents` while in the system32 folder, especially if you are new to using Powershell. You may also want to edit your image to hide the longer number in the path you're working with for privacy.

Make sure the Steam application is closed and try:

`Clear-Content 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\YOUR_ID\440\remote'`

Make sure your ID is correct.

You may want to avoid this approach all together and try a more [common method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORgRe6R51Rw).